# Trying to Run Webdriver with compiled JavaFX Application

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, javafx, webdriver

I am building an application with the excellent webdriver framework. Firstly, I'd like to point out that I am extremely new to Java. Started learning it about 3-4 days ago and think it's great to use so far! I am using IntelliJ (I use PyCharm, so it was an obvious choice for me)

Anyway, down to the problem. I've began writing my code and all is going well, then I decided I should probably make a start on the GUI. So I created a new JavaFX application in IntelliJ, added my existing code, made a button (w00t, go me!) and made it so that it would run a method which loads up a chromedriver instance and loads a webpage. When I hit run within IntelliJ, it works as intended. However when I build the artifacts I cannot get it to work. The application loads with my shiny GUI, I click the button and nothing happens. Initially I assumed the directory to the chromedriver was wrong, so I set an absolute path to it (which I know to be correct). It still didn't work. I then tried loading the app with java -jar JavaFXApp.jar. It loaded fine, clicked the button and then I had a whole host of errors. I have had a look around, but due to me being a noob, could not figure it out.
Here is the output

> > Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> >     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)     at
> >     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> >       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
> >       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at
> >     javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)  at
> >     javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)   at
> >     javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)     at
> >     com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> >       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
> >       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
> >     javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)  at
> >     javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)  at
> >     javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)  at
> >     javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)    at
> >     javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)  at
> >     com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
> >       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> >     com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
> >       at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)    at
> >     com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898) Caused by:
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >       at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
> >     sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)    at
> >     sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
> >     sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)   at
> >     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)     ...
> >     43 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException    at
> >     BetBot.Controller.TestT(Controller.java:16)   ... 53 more Caused by:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException    at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)    at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 54 more

Here is the Controller.java file. It's pretty standard.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class Controller {

public void TestT(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        MainProg.main();
    }
}
```

MainProg.java contents;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MainProg {
    public static void main() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Adam/IdeaProjects/Driver/OSX/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("Http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

If I set the TestT function to just set the value of a textfield to "Hello World" I don't get any issues.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the contents of ` MainProg.main();` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I completely forgot. It was late when I was posting this. Thanks

Comment: The main culprit is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Yeah I can see that, I just don't understand it. I'm not even looking for an element. All the program does is load up a chromedriver instance :S

Comment: Do you have `selenium-java.jar` and all its dependent jars in the classpath ?

Comment: I realised the issue before seeing this comment, but thank you anyway!

Comment: An advice, most of the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` occurs because of missing jar in your build path !

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Me being the noob I am, forgot to add the chromedriver jar to the build folder. All working fine now.